# Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType )

Tags: java, generics, autowired

I have the following classes in the follwing pattern:

```
public abstract class BaseDAOMongoImpl<K, E extends Entity> implements BaseDAO<K, E> {
    public BaseDAOMongoImpl() {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        entityClass = (Class<E>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        entityClassName = entityClass.getSimpleName();
    }
...
}

@Repository
public class TestDAO1Impl extends BaseDAOMongoImpl<String, Test1MockEvent> {
    public String getOverridingCollectionName() {
        return "test1";
    }
}

@Repository
public class Test123 extends TestDAO1Impl {
    public void testing(){

    }
```

Now, when I am auto-wiring `Test123` in some class I am getting the following exception:

```
Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType )
```

I tried to write a recursive function that returns a the proper class name in the base class construct like below:

```
public BaseDAOMongoImpl() {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)getClassThatExtendsBaseDAOMongoImpl(this.getClass()).getGenericSuperclass(); 
        this.entityClass = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        this.entityClassName = this.entityClass.getSimpleName();
        this.isAuditable = this.isAuditableEntity(this.entityClass);
        LOGGER.debug("entity class:{}, isAuditable:{}", new Object[]{this.entityClass, this.isAuditable});
}

private Class<?> getClassThatExtendsBaseDAOMongoImpl(Class<?> source) {
        if (BaseDAOMongoImpl.class.getCanonicalName().equals(source.getSuperclass().getCanonicalName()))
            return source;
        return getClassThatExtendsBaseDAOMongoImpl(source.getSuperclass());
    }
```

But I am getting the below exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Test1DAOImpl' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: test123,test1DAOImpl
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is now solved by adding @Qualifies test123 and Test1DAOImpl along with the above  changes

Comment: Consider submitting the answer to your question. That will help more SO users who view your question.